# How to obtain a kerberos service ticket via GSS-API?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos

Does anyone know how to get a service ticket from the Key Distribution Center (KDC) using the Java GSS-API?

I have a thick-client-application that first authenticates via JAAS using the Krb5LoginModule to fetch the TGT from the ticket cache (background: Windows e.g. uses a kerberos implementation and stores the ticket granting ticket in a secure memory area). From the LoginManager I get the Subject object which contains the TGT. Now I hoped when I create a specific GSSCredential object for my service, the service ticket will be put into the Subject's private credentials as well (I've read so somewhere in the web). So I have tried the following:

```
// Exception handling ommitted
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("HelloEjbClient", new DialogCallbackHandler());
lc.login()
Subject.doAs(lc.getSubject(), new PrivilegedAction() {

    public Object run() {
        GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
        GSSName clientName = manager.createName("clientUser", GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
        GSSCredential clientCreds = manager.createCredential(clientName, 8 * 3600, createKerberosOid(), GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

        GSSName serverName = manager.createName("myService@localhost", GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);
        manager.createCredential(serverName, GSSCredential.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME, createKerberosOid(), GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);
        return null;
    }

    private Oid createKerberosOid() {
        return new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
    }

});
```

Unfortunately I get a GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My understanding of getting the service ticket was wrong. I do not need to get the credentials from the service - this is not possible on the client, because the client really doesn't have a TGT for the server and therefore doesn't have the rights to get the service credentials.
What's just missing here is to create a new GSSContext and to initialize it. The return value from this method contains the service ticket, if I have understood that correctly. Here is a working code example. It must be run in a PrivilegedAction on behalf of a logged in subject:

```
    GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    GSSName clientName = manager.createName("clientUser", GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
    GSSCredential clientCred = manager.createCredential(clientName,
                                                        8 * 3600,
                                                        createKerberosOid(),
                                                        GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

    GSSName serverName = manager.createName("http@server", GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE);

    GSSContext context = manager.createContext(serverName,
                                               createKerberosOid(),
                                               clientCred,
                                               GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
    context.requestMutualAuth(true);
    context.requestConf(false);
    context.requestInteg(true);

    byte[] outToken = context.initSecContext(new byte[0], 0, 0);
    System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(outToken));
    context.dispose();
```

The outToken contains then contains the Service Ticket. However this is not the way the GSS-API was meant to be used. Its goal was to hide those details to the code, so it is better to establish a GSSContext using the GSS-API on both sides. Otherwise you really should know what you are doing because of potential security holes.
For more information read the [Sun SSO tutorial with kerberos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html) more carefully than I did.

EDIT:
Just forgot that I am using Windows XP with SP2. There is a new "feature" in this version of Windows that disallows using the TGT in the Windows RAM. You have to edit the registry to allow this. For more information have a look at the [JGSS Troubleshooting page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html) topic in case you experience a "KrbException: KDC has no support for encryption type (14)" like I did.

Comment: @Michael: Thank you for your contribution. As you can see I wrote this quite some time ago so I don't remember the exact details, but I am pretty sure this was just meant as an example. What do you think can be done to improve this answer?

Comment: check your link to Sun SSO tutorial with kerberos and have a look at figure 6. There is the loop I wrote about.

Comment: I think I did not include the loop because I couldn't figure out what the readToken() and sendToken(...) methods are supposed to do.

Comment: in case of HTTP `readToken` request an HTTP response and extracts the token, `sendToken` performs the opposite.

Comment: Can this token creation be used with two users on Active Directory i.e. user1 as Client making an http api call passing this token to user2 as http server. If i understand it correctly server should be able to decrypt this token.

Answer (score 10):

I had a lot of problems to use this code, but I have at least a solution. I post it here, perhaps it will help some of you...

```
/**
 * Tool to retrieve a kerberos ticket. This one will not be stored in the windows ticket cache.
 */
public final class KerberosTicketRetriever
{
    private final static Oid KERB_V5_OID;
    private final static Oid KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID;

    static {
        try
        {
            KERB_V5_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
            KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.1");

        } catch (final GSSException ex)
        {
            throw new Error(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Not to be instanciated
     */
    private KerberosTicketRetriever() {};

    /**
     *
     */
    private static class TicketCreatorAction implements PrivilegedAction
    {
        final String userPrincipal;
        final String applicationPrincipal;

        private StringBuffer outputBuffer;

        /**
         *
         * @param userPrincipal  p.ex. <tt>MuelleHA@MYFIRM.COM</tt>
         * @param applicationPrincipal  p.ex. <tt>HTTP/webserver.myfirm.com</tt>
         */
        private TicketCreatorAction(final String userPrincipal, final String applicationPrincipal)
        {
            this.userPrincipal = userPrincipal;
            this.applicationPrincipal = applicationPrincipal;
        }

        private void setOutputBuffer(final StringBuffer newOutputBuffer)
        {
            outputBuffer = newOutputBuffer;
        }

        /**
         * Only calls {@link #createTicket()}
         * @return <tt>null</tt>
         */
        public Object run()
        {
            try
            {
                createTicket();
            }
            catch (final GSSException  ex)
            {
                throw new Error(ex);
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @throws GSSException
         */
        private void createTicket () throws GSSException
        {
            final GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
            final GSSName clientName = manager.createName(userPrincipal, KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);
            final GSSCredential clientCred = manager.createCredential(clientName,
                    8 * 3600,
                    KERB_V5_OID,
                    GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

            final GSSName serverName = manager.createName(applicationPrincipal, KRB5_PRINCIPAL_NAME_OID);

            final GSSContext context = manager.createContext(serverName,
                    KERB_V5_OID,
                    clientCred,
                    GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME);
            context.requestMutualAuth(true);
            context.requestConf(false);
            context.requestInteg(true);

            final byte[] outToken = context.initSecContext(new byte[0], 0, 0);

            if (outputBuffer !=null)
            {
                outputBuffer.append(String.format("Src Name: %s\n", context.getSrcName()));
                outputBuffer.append(String.format("Target  : %s\n", context.getTargName()));
                outputBuffer.append(new BASE64Encoder().encode(outToken));
                outputBuffer.append("\n");
            }

            context.dispose();
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param realm p.ex. <tt>MYFIRM.COM</tt>
     * @param kdc p.ex. <tt>kerbserver.myfirm.com</tt>
     * @param applicationPrincipal   cf. {@link #TicketCreatorAction(String, String)}
     * @throws GSSException
     * @throws LoginException
     */
    static public String retrieveTicket(
            final String realm,
            final String kdc,
            final String applicationPrincipal)
    throws GSSException, LoginException
    {

        // create the jass-config-file
        final File jaasConfFile;
        try
        {
            jaasConfFile = File.createTempFile("jaas.conf", null);
            final PrintStream bos = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(jaasConfFile));
            bos.print(String.format(
                    "Krb5LoginContext { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required refreshKrb5Config=true useTicketCache=true debug=true ; };"
            ));
            bos.close();
            jaasConfFile.deleteOnExit();
        }
        catch (final IOException ex)
        {
            throw new IOError(ex);
        }

        // set the properties
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", realm);
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", kdc);
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config",jaasConfFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // get the Subject(), i.e. the current user under Windows
        final Subject subject = new Subject();
        final LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("Krb5LoginContext", subject, new DialogCallbackHandler());
        lc.login();

        // extract our principal
        final Set<Principal> principalSet = subject.getPrincipals();
        if (principalSet.size() != 1)
            throw new AssertionError("No or several principals: " + principalSet);
        final Principal userPrincipal = principalSet.iterator().next();

        // now try to execute the SampleAction as the authenticated Subject
        // action.run() without doAsPrivileged leads to
        //   No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        final TicketCreatorAction action = new TicketCreatorAction(userPrincipal.getName(), applicationPrincipal);
        final StringBuffer outputBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        action.setOutputBuffer(outputBuffer);
        Subject.doAsPrivileged(lc.getSubject(), action, null);

        return outputBuffer.toString();
    }

    public static void main (final String args[]) throws Throwable
    {
        final String ticket = retrieveTicket("MYFIRM.COM", "kerbserver", "HTTP/webserver.myfirm.com");
        System.out.println(ticket);
    }
}
```